# Вывод ссылок на файлы

Tags: файлы, php, пути

На сайте есть папка с файлами, необходимо вывести список файлов со ссылкой на них вида -

- file1 | http://example.com/path/files/upload/file1.ext
- file2 | http://example.com/path/files/upload/file2.ext

Comment: Проблема в чем?

Comment: Проблема в получении ссылки такого вида.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dir  = 'папка';

$files = scandir($dir);

foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
    echo '<a href="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/папка/'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a> <br/>';
}
```

Comment: Вот в этом вся и проблема, если скрипт с папкой находится в корне - всё хорошо, но если переместить их какую либо папку - ссылки на файл будут выводиться неверно.
Не донёс свою мысль в первом посте - нужно сделать верный вывод ссылок не зависимо от места размещения скрипта с папкой и без прописывания жёстких путей.